# Implement Background Music with Pause/Play Icon in JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello and thank you in advance. I'm quite newto JQuery/Javascript and am unsure how to implement my embedded background music with my pause/play icons. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
       <div id="toggle" class="play" style="width: 314px; height: 311px"></div>
       <script type="text/javascript"></script>



     $(document).ready(function() {
       $('#music').attr("class", "false");
        $('#toggle').bind("click", function() {

        if ($(this).attr("class") == "play")

        $(this).attr("class", "pause");


        else
        $(this).attr("class", "play");


        });

        });
```

Comment: Is this actually what your code looks like? Is there a closing div somewhere as well? What behavior are you seeing with this? oh and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: The JS was included in a seperate file and I pulled the html from my webpage. Mainly what I'm asking, is how can I turn off the background music with the jquery code? And thank you!

Comment: Like how do I get the music to play when the play icon is displayed and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

The Sound is Placed in an Empty Span

The JavaScript places an embed tag inside an empty span tag when the script is initiated. So, you need to add the following span file somewhere within the body of your HTML page, preferabl near the top of the document:

```
<span id="dummy"></span>
Call the Script with an onmouseover or onclick Attribute
```

The last thing you need to add is an element that you want to generate the sound on click or on mouseover. Call the script with one of those attributes:

```
<a href="#" onclick="playSound('URL to soundfile');">Click here to hear a sound</a>

 <p onmouseover="playSound('URL to soundfile');">Mouse over this text to hear a sound</p>
```